# TFS 2013 audit get latest version commands

Tags: tfs, audit, tfvc

We're using TFS 2013.  I'm interested to know if it's possible to see which developers are performing a 'Get Latest Version' command from various projects.  tbl_command shows Get commands, but this doesn't tell me what was gotten.  Is this available somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would open up the SQL Transaction inspection tool and see any sql transactions that are happening (this will take some trial and error to tune the filters to find what transactions you are looking for).  Then when you find the table that is being queried specifically for a "Get Latest Version" and not just a regular "Get", then just as a sql table trigger that fires an INSERT trigger into another table that keeps track of Who, What, When, and Where this is happening.  I'm sorry I cannot give you the details of what transaction this is happening, but I've done this methodology to find transactions when I need to keep track of when developers were adding LABELS to TFSVC branches and now I can know when they are sneaking in labels anywhere in my TFS system.

Comment: Thanks Antebios.  I was also considering a trigger before confirming the info I'm looking for isn't readily available in TFS.  I'll go this route.

Answer (score 1):

Every time a developer performs a get-latest, the server updates its Workspace tracking tables. Through these, you can track exactly which workspace mappings and which version of each element in the workspace mapping has been served to a user through TFVC commands.

A user can delete their workspace from the server, after which this information is lost however.

If you want to use this data for audit purposes, it may not be enough.

Files downloaded through `tf vc view` commands are not stored in the workspace cache, even though that command can be used to download individual files. Individual file downloads through the Web UI are also not tracked in any workspace cache.

Each file downloaded result in a HTTP call on the TFS application tier and those logs should provide data on which files were downloaded by which user.

If you don't have all the logs and haven't configured high retention on the tbl_command, then you should consider that each user with access permissions potentially has downloaded all files they have the permissions for.

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  Good info here.